# Processing Serial Port String data in C# very fast

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have my serial port data coming from STM32 in string format in the following way

```
Array_A 0.0382, 0.0382, 0.0382, 0.0382, 0.0382, 0.0382, 0.0389, 0.0394, 0.0382
Array_B 0.0077, 0.0077, 0.0077, 0.0077, 0.0077, 0.0077, 0.0077, 0.0077, 0.0077
```

My processing code for the data is as follows

```
if (RadioButtonA.Checked || RadioButtonB.Checked)
                {   
                    string StrSerialIn = SerialPort1.ReadExisting();
                    string StrSerialInRam;
                    System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox TB = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
                    TB.Multiline = true;
                    TB.Text = StrSerialIn;
                    StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines[0];
                    if (StrSerialInRam.Contains("Poti"))
                    {
                        textBox2.Text = StrSerialInRam;
                    }
                    StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines[0].Substring(0, 8);
                    if (StrSerialInRam == "Array_A ")
                    {
                        Sen_A = TB.Lines[0];
                        string[] valA = Sen_A.Split(',');
                        S1A_Val = valA[0].Substring(8);
                        S2A_Val = valA[1];
                        S3A_Val = valA[2];
                        S4A_Val = valA[3];
                        S5A_Val = valA[4];
                        S6A_Val = valA[5];
                        S7A_Val = valA[6];
                        S8A_Val = valA[7];
                        S9A_Val = valA[8];
                    }
                    Sen_A = "";
                    StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines[1];
                    if (StrSerialInRam.Contains("Poti"))
                    {
                        textBox2.Text = StrSerialInRam;
                    }
                    StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines[1].Substring(0, 8);
                    if (StrSerialInRam == "Array_B ")
                    {
                        Sen_B = TB.Lines[1];
                        string[] valB = Sen_B.Split(',');
                        S1B_Val = valB[0].Substring(8);
                        S2B_Val = valB[1];
                        S3B_Val = valB[2];
                        S4B_Val = valB[3];
                        S5B_Val = valB[4];
                        S6B_Val = valB[5];
                        S7B_Val = valB[6];
                        S8B_Val = valB[7];
                        S9B_Val = valB[8];                        
                    }
                    Sen_B = "";
                    StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines[2];
                    if (StrSerialInRam.Contains("Poti"))
                    {
                        textBox2.Text = StrSerialInRam;
                    }
                }
```

My problem is that the current processing of data is done at around 30 Hz but I want my data to be processed as fast as possible around 350Hz - 400Hz. Currently, I am losing some data due to slow processing. Is there any fastest way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using TextBox and RichTextBox Controls to process your data? Also, never (ever) use the `Lines` property, unless time doesn't count at all. Use StringBuilder objects to store your data. Don't use UI elements in any way.

Comment: All your code logic is contained in one method. You should split into UI logic and network logic in different methods (or async Tasks/Threads). Mixing both together will cause performance issues both on the UI (which freezes or responds slowly) and the network data processing.

Comment: @Jimi - I haven't used StringBuilder objects. Can you please just give some examples or references? I have to extract each value of Array data coming from STM and store it in datagridview.

Comment: I suggest you rebuild your code, the [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) class functionality is simple to understand. You also need to better explain what your data is made of, e.g., why  you have all those `if (StrSerialInRam.Contains("Poti")) { textBox2.Text = StrSerialInRam; }` there. You have to specify how you receive the data. A Serial port usually implies events (e.g., `DataReceived`) raised in a Thread other than the UI Thread. *High speed* (let's call it that) requires smart buffering, probably handling a queue.

Comment: The DataGridView update is another thing completely. What DataSource are you using? What interaction is expected? Can a User read /evaluate values at the speed you want to achieve? -- The .Net version also counts, etc.

Comment: @Jimi -  `if (StrSerialInRam.Contains("Poti")) { textBox2.Text = StrSerialInRam; }` - This code is when the user sends the command from the GUI to STM to extract a particular Array value then the STM will take the command from GUI and send the respective array value through the serial port. So I am using this command to check the value send by STM and display it on the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend process data in separate thread and using binary protocol from you MCU.

To transmit a data structure use struct in MCU:

```
typedef struct{
    int Data1;
    int Data2;
}myStruct;
```

Use for example RFC1662 standard to make frames.

**On the C# site:**

1. In DataReceived receive all incomming data and put in RFC1662 class.
2. In PacketReceived you get byte[] buffer of one entire packet.
3. Convert byte[] to structure.
4. Push structure tu SyncBuffer in order to synchronization.
5. Present data for example using Timer Tick and use PopItems.

Good luck!

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        syncBuffer = new SyncBuffer<MyData>();

        sp = new SerialPort();
        sp.PortName = "COM1";
        sp.BaudRate = 9600; // Use higher baudrate
        sp.DataReceived += Sp_DataReceived;

        rfc = new RFC1662();
        rfc.PacketError += Rfc_PacketError;
        rfc.PacketReceived += Rfc_PacketReceived;
    }



    SerialPort sp;
    RFC1662 rfc;
    SyncBuffer<MyData> syncBuffer;

    private void Sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Receive data stream
        while(sp.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            int length = sp.BytesToRead;
            byte[] buff = new byte[length];
            sp.Read(buff, 0, length);
            rfc.PutData(buff, length);
        }
    }

    private void Rfc_PacketReceived(byte[] buffer)
    {
        // One frame (structure) received
        MyData data = LowLevelUtils.FromBytes<MyData>(buffer);
        syncBuffer.PushItem(data); // Put to buffer
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Periodically pop items from buffer
        MyData[] data = syncBuffer.PopItems();
        foreach (MyData item in data)
        {
            // Present one data message
        }
    }

    private void Rfc_PacketError(Exception ex, byte[] buffer)
    {
        // Handle packet error
    }

    public struct MyData
    {
        public int Data1;
        public int Data2;
    }
```

RFC1662:

```
public class RFC1662
{
    public const byte STX = 0x7E;
    public const byte ESC = 0x7D;
    public readonly byte[] ESC_STX = { 0x7D, 0x5E };
    public readonly byte[] ESC_ESC = { 0x7D, 0x5D };

    public RFC1662()
    {
        m = new MemoryStream();
        writer = new BinaryWriter(m);
    }
    
    public delegate void DlgPacketReceived(byte[] buffer);
    public event DlgPacketReceived PacketReceived;

    public delegate void DlgPacketError(Exception ex, byte[] buffer);
    public event DlgPacketError PacketError;

    MemoryStream m;
    BinaryWriter writer;

    public void PutData(byte[] data, int length)
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            byte b = data[i];
            if (b == STX)
            {
                byte[] buffer = m.ToArray();
                if (buffer.Length > 0)
                {
                    bool bufferOK = false;
                    try
                    {
                        buffer = RemoveEscSequences(buffer);
                        bufferOK = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if (this.PacketError != null)
                            this.PacketError(ex, buffer);
                    }

                    if (this.PacketReceived != null && bufferOK)
                        this.PacketReceived(buffer);
                }
                m.Dispose();
                writer.Dispose();
                m = new MemoryStream();
                writer = new BinaryWriter(m);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.Write(b);
            }
        }                        
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Decode message from RFC1662 standard
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buffer"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public byte[] RemoveEscSequences(byte[] buffer)
    {
        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(m))
            {
                int length = buffer.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    byte b = buffer[i];
                    switch (b)
                    {
                        case ESC:
                            i++;
                            if (buffer[i] == ESC_STX[1])
                            {
                                writer.Write(STX);
                            }
                            else if (buffer[i] == ESC_ESC[1])
                            {
                                writer.Write(ESC);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw new FormatException("RFC1662 Corupted");
                            }

                            break;
                        default:
                            writer.Write(b);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return m.ToArray();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Code message to RFC1622 standard
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buffer"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public byte[] RemoveSpecialCharacters(byte[] buffer)
    {
        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(m))
            {
                int length = buffer.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    byte b = buffer[i];
                    switch (b)
                    {
                        case STX:
                            writer.Write(ESC_STX);
                            break;
                        case ESC:
                            writer.Write(ESC_ESC);
                            break;
                        default:
                            writer.Write(b);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return m.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

SyncBuffer:

```
public class SyncBuffer<T>
{
    private List<T> data = new List<T>();
    /// <summary>
    /// Add item to collection to the end
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    public void PushItem(T item)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            data.Add(item);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clear colection
    /// </summary>
    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            data.Clear();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get items from collection and clear collection
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T[] PopItems()
    {
        T[] ret;
        lock (this)
        {
            ret = data.ToArray();
            data.Clear();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            int count;
            lock (this)
            {
                count = data.Count;
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

LowLevelUtils:

```
public static class LowLevelUtils
{
    public static byte[] GetBytes<T>(T str) where T : struct
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
        byte[] arr = new byte[size];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return arr;
    }

    public static T FromBytes<T>(byte[] arr) where T : struct
    {
        T str = new T();
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, ptr, size);

        str = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, str.GetType());
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return str;
    }
}
```